# Did Thales believe in Hylozoism?

Tags: aristotle, presocratics, thales

Aristotle states that Thales believed that "the soul is mixed in with the whole universe" and that "all things are full of gods," which seem to imply a belief in Hylozoism. However, later in the same passage, Aristotle describes Thales' argument that "the soul is something productive of motion," and uses a magnet as an example. This point would seem to contradict Hylozoism, as not all things are "productive of motion," at least not in anyway noticeable to an ancient person.

Comment: Same answer of [this post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/12844/did-thales-really-argue-this): nothing directly attributed to Thales that has come down to us, but Aristotle mention Thales' views in his books.

Comment: See [Thales: Fragments](http://demonax.info/doku.php?id=text:thales_fragments)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome, Tommy Greim

We have to rely mainly on Aristotle for our 'knowledge' of Thales' beliefs. Aristotle tells us (though under the proviso of *labon isos* - an admission of conjecture) that for Thales water is the primary substance of the world (Kirk, Raven, Schofield 89); that the world rests on water (Kirk, Raven, Schofield 86); that everything is full of gods (Kirk, Raven, Schofield 90: *panta plere theon*);  and that the lodestone has a soul (Kirk, Raven, Schofield 91, 92). If we take hylozoism as the idea that everything in nature is animate - has some form of consciousness - then it might seem hard to see how Thales can resist classification as a hylozoist since if everything is full of gods, everything is full of beings, namely gods, who possess consciousness.

However, *plere* in the sense of 'full of' is not totally clear. It may not mean 'contains nothing but' but rather 'crammed or laden with'. In which case a natural object might be crammed or laden with conscious gods without itself being conscious.

Mauro is right: we do not really know what Thales held exactly. Aristotle, our principal source, is not a particularly reliable historian of philosophy.

*Reference*

Kirk, Raven & Schofield  - G. S. Kirk; J. E. Raven; M. Schofield, The Presocratic Philosophers : A Critical History with a Selcetion of Texts, ISBN 10: 0521274559 / ISBN 13: 9780521274555
Published by Cambridge University Press, 1984. References in answer are to Thales fragment numbers.

D. R. Dicks, 'Thales', The Classical Quarterly , Nov., 1959, Vol. 9, No. 2 (Nov., 1959), pp. 294-309: 296.